# Raspberry pi 3 freezes randomly every day

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

My raspberry pi 3 freezes randomly, average three times per day. When it freezes the only thing I can do is to restart it by unplug it from power outlet and plug it again. 
Power charger I use is the original raspberry pi charger. I also have heatsinks and fan. Average temperature is about 50 Celsius when it freezes. I have always connected an external HD (USB 3, 6TB) with it's own power. Raspberry runs plex media server, homebridge, transmission and it's connected to internet through both wlan0 and eth0 at the same time. It also is updated to the latest Raspbian, kernel "Linux raspi 4.14.50-v7+ #1122 SMP Tue Jun 19 12:26:26 BST 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux". 
Here is the dmesg log "https://www.dropbox.com/s/1hnqkxfkw96xo8q/log?dl=0".
Any help why it freezes would much appreciated.

Comment: Check the power voltage carefully while it is running. Extension header pin 2 should be rock steady at 5-5.25V.  I also would swap in another Pi to see if the problem is specific to one board.

Comment: can you post all the instances of /var/log/syslog* so that I can check if it shows any inconsistency there which might help in finding out the problem